# Location entra em looping somente acima da versão API 23 Android 6.0(Marshmallow), por que?

Tags: android, geolocalização

O problema é que nas versões acima (testei nas APIs 23, 24, 27) ,(na API 29 ta funcionando) o deburger mostra centenas de passagens pelo onLocationAvailability
pois botei um Log.i.
Isso retorna sempre   TRUE como segue abaixo na versão kitkat API 19 :

```
I/locationAvailability :: true
I/Location pos ->: 38.4219983 -122.08430/08/2019 23:21:39
I/locationAvailability :: false
I/Location pos ->: 38.4219983 -122.08430/08/2019 23:22:10
I/locationAvailability :: true
Process 3298 terminated.
```

Mas nas versões acima da API 23 temos :

```
I/Location Active: true
I/Location Active: true
I/Location Active: true
I/Location Active: true
I/Location Active: true
I/Location Active: true
I/Location Active: true ...... ao infinito.
```

Nem mostra a a posição de latitude e longitude  ! Será que tenho que usar outra implementação para as versões 23 e acima ??? Percebi que na versão 23, 24 e 25 o aplicativo recebe as permissões, posso ver dentro do emulador,permissões ativadas. Mas a função volta a atuar e abrir as caixas de dialogo para pedir de novo as permissões.

```
   protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    addDataHora();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!hasPhonePermissions( this, Permissions )) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this,Permissions,Permission_All );
        }else{
            TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (tMgr != null) {
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
                phoneNumber = mPhoneNumber;
            }
        }
    }
    int errorcode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable( MainActivity.this );
    switch (errorcode) {
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED:
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog( MainActivity.this, errorcode, 0, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    finish();
                }
            } ).show();
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            break;
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        return;
    }
    client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            } else {
                Log.i( "location - ", "null" );
            }
        }
    } ).addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        }
    } );
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval( 20000 );
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval( 10000 ); //location computed for other apps
    locationRequest.setPriority( LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY ); //uso preciso com gps.
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest( locationRequest );
    SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient( this );
    settingsClient.checkLocationSettings( builder.build() ).addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
            Log.i( "Location Active ", locationSettingsResponse.getLocationSettingsStates().isNetworkLocationPresent() + "" );
        }
    } ).addOnFailureListener( new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                try {
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult( MainActivity.this, 10 );
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException el) {
                    //todo
                }
            }
        }
    } );
    //Listener pega sempre a nova posição do provider. Kill app se local é nulo.
    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            if (locationResult == null) {
                Log.i( "Local position -> ", "local is null");
                return;
            }
            //procurar na lista de localização.
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                addDataHora();
                Log.i( "Location pos -> ", location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude() + DataTime );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
            Log.i( "locationAvailability : ", locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable() + "" );
        }
    };
    client.requestLocationUpdates( locationRequest, locationCallback, null );
    Context context = this;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences( PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE );
    String tentativas = sharedPreferences.getString( "tentativas","0" );
    atemptcount = Integer.parseInt( tentativas );
 //   Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Load config: "+ tentativas, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
//FIM RESUME

 @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (locationCallback != null) {
        stopLocationUpdate();
    }

/** Remove recursos para liberar memória  */
private void stopLocationUpdate() {
    client.removeLocationUpdates( locationCallback );
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@RequiresApi(api = VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE){
        if(grantResults.length > 0  && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Permissão aceita" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this, "Permissão negada" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Descobri que um problema nas permissões mesmo. Na API 29 é reconhecido as permissões. E o programa avança. Na versão 24 por exemplo, que to testando mais. Ele pede a validação das permissões, mas de alguma forma, não são computadas. E fica num looping na função que valida as permissões.

Comment: Creio que seja cedo para você "fechar" a perguntar. Para ajudar quem vai responder também, coloque o trecho da sua função onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: Coloquei wryel o problema na versão 23 e 25 é bem pior, o icone do gps fica piscando 3 vezes por segundo.

Comment: instalei diversas vezes emuladores diferentes para a api 23 , usei um telefone real, e apresenta o mesmo problema. na api 25 mesmo problema. As outras APIs 19, 21,24,  e perfeito nas versões 26,27,28,29. Quase desistindo. Pena que grande parte das pessoas ainda usa a versão 23 à 25...

Comment: Na versão api 25 o programa passa varias vezes no onResume, lança muitos Logs pra mim. Mostrando intenso trabalho nessa parte do programa. coisas que as versoes estaveis não fazem. Seria normal o programa passas sentenas de vezes pelo onResume ? Me parece bem anormal. Ele até pega a localização que eu quero, mas to achando muito trabalho no local.

Comment: Ninguém  quer ajudar com essa resposta ?